# Elliptic Integral along complex path

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, elliptic-curves, elliptic-integrals, elliptic-functions

I am interested in the following integral
\begin{align}
\int \frac{dt}{t\sqrt{(t-e_1)(t-e_2)(t-e_3)}}
\end{align}
where $e_1=\bar{e}_3$ and $e_2\in\mathbb{R}$ is negativ. Assume that the branch cut of the square root goes to minus infinity. Also assume that the real part of $e_1$, and hence of $e_3$, is greater than zero. I want to perform the integration along the straight vertical path from $e_1$ to $e_3$ and rewrite it in terms of elliptic integrals of first, second or third kind. A suitable reference is of course the book *Handbook of elliptic functions* by *Byrd, Friedman* and on page 89 they the consider this integral by integrating along the *real* line. For example, integrating  from $e_2$ to minus infinity the integral takes a particular easy form (see page 94, eq. 245.06 and page 216, eq. 361.60 with $f_1=0$).

I feel like the form for integrating from $e_1$ to $e_3$ should be similar since we are still integrating between the branch points. Maybe someone can help me or post a reference for similar problems?

Edit: The case I mentioned above is
\begin{align}
  \int_{-\infty}^{e_2}\frac{dt}{t\sqrt{(t-e_1)(t-e_2)(t-e_3)}}=c\int_{0}^{u_1}\frac{1-cnu}{1+\alpha\, cn u}
\end{align}
for some constants $c,\alpha$ depending on the $e_i$ and $cn u_1=-1$. The right hand side can be simplified to
\begin{align}
  \frac{1}{\alpha}(-2K(m)+\frac{2}{1-\alpha}\Pi(\frac{\alpha^2}{\alpha^2-1},m))
\end{align}
where $K$ and $\Pi$ are the complete elliptic integrals of the first and third kind, respectively.

Edit2: I kind of found the solution by myself but this will probably not work in the general case because I have some additional information. Nevertheless, maybe the edit will help someone else. The following calculation should be right modulo signs.

Assume that the imaginary part of $e_1$ is greater than zero (which is no restriction since we can just exchange $e_1$ and $e_3$). The additional information I have is that I know the imaginary part of the integral
\begin{align*}
  \int_{e_1}^{e_2}\frac{dt}{t\sqrt{(t-e_1)(t-e_2)(t-e_3)}}.
\end{align*}
Denote the imaginary part of this integral by $v$. Since $\int_{e_1}^{e_3}$ is completely imaginary and $\int_{e_1}^{e_3}+\int_{e_3}^{\infty}+\int_{\infty}^{e_1}=0$ by the residue theorem we get $\textrm{Im}\int_{e_1}^{\infty}=\frac{1}{2}\textrm{Im}\int_{e_1}^{e_3}$. On the other hand $\int_{e_1}^{e_2}+\int_{e_2}^{e_3}+\int_{e_3}^{e_1}=2\pi i$ and hence $\int_{e_3}^{e_1}=2\pi i - 2 i v$ (as the imaginary part of $\int_{e_1}^{e_2}$ and  $\int_{e_2}^{e_3}$ are the same). Therefore
\begin{align*}
  \textrm{Im}\int_{e_1}^{\infty}=\pi  - v.
\end{align*}
By holomorphicity $\int_{e_1}^{e_2}=\int_{e_1}^{-\infty}+\int_{-\infty}^{e_2}$ (above the branch cut). However, we also have $\textrm{Im}\int_{e_1}^{\infty}=\textrm{Im}\int_{e_1}^{-\infty}$ we and hence
\begin{align*} 
  \textrm{Im}\int_{e_1}^{\infty}=v-\textrm{Im}\int_{e_2}^{-\infty}.
\end{align*}
The integral $\int_{e_2}^{-\infty}$ is purely imaginary. Putting these equations together we can express the integral $\int_{e_1}^{e_3}$ in terms of some constants and the formula for $\int_{e_2}^{-\infty}$ in my first edit. Again, I did not take care of the signs in the integrations at all so be careful there.

**Remark:** For the general case I tried to identify $\wp=x$ and then use the relations of Weierstrass elliptic functions for rhombic tori, i.e. $\wp(z)=e_2+H_2\frac{1+cn(z';m)}{1-cn(z';m)}$ (see Abramowitz/Stegun p. 649 for the notation).  We can integrate the Jacobi ellitpic functions (eq. 361.60 from *Handbook of ellitpic functions*) and for the elliptic integral of the third kind I tried using the identities of the book *Elliptic functions and applications, Lawden* on page 76. But unfortunately I did not succed and mathematica always gave me wrong results.